# After Selecting date from datepicker bootbox modal hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootbox

**"Add New" Button Code :**

```
    $('#AddButton').on('click', function() {
               bootbox
            .dialog({
                title: 'Add Transfer Details',
                message: $('#userForm'),
                show: false // We will show it manually later
            })
            .on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
                $('#userForm')
                    .show();
            })
            .on('hide.bs.modal', function(e) {
                // Bootbox will remove the modal (including the body which contains the login form)
                // after hiding the modal
                // Therefor, we need to backup the form
                $('#userForm').hide().appendTo('body');
            })
            .modal('show');
    });
```

After Clicking on button above code run and display a bootbox popup.
I have datepicker inside this modal. After selecting date from datepicker, my bootbox modal immediatly hide.Please help why this is happening.
**My datepicker code:**

```
    $('#payDate').datepicker({
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    }).on('changeDate', function(e){
        $(this).datepicker('hide');
    });
```

**UPDATED :**

Jsfiddle link(This problem I am facing)

https://jsfiddle.net/paramj/sww1dnvk/3/

Comment: if possible please create a fiddle of the problem.

Comment: try changing `$(this).datepicker('hide');` to `$(#payDate).hide();`

Comment: @Kartikeya Khosla fiddle created please check

Comment: @Bruno no,  its not working

Comment: @Paramjeet..nt able to understand exactly what is the problem but get it working for you.see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/KartikeyaKhosla/sww1dnvk/14/)

Comment: @Kartikeya Khosla Thank you sir your code is working for me. You save my day. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have posted is wrong,you modal is not getting hidden.Its the 
input type text field on your modal.because of the following line

```
$(this).datepicker('hide');
```

Replace

```
$('#payDate').datepicker({
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    }).on('changeDate', function(e){
        $(this).datepicker('hide');
    });
```

with

```
$('#payDate').datepicker({
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    }).on('change', function(){
        $('.datepicker').hide();
    });
```

because when ever you are using 'this' its selecting the input type text('id=payDate') field as the document element and applying jquery hide on it.

And The blunder is done here

```
 .on('hide.bs.modal', function(e) {
                // Bootbox will remove the modal (including the body which contains the login form)
                // after hiding the modal
                // Therefor, we need to backup the form
                $('#userForm').hide().appendTo('body');
            })
```

remove

```
$('#userForm').hide().appendTo('body');
```

so the resultant javascript snippet will be

```
$('#AddButton').on('click', function() {

            bootbox
                .dialog({
                    title: 'Add Transfer Details',
                    message: $('#userForm'),
                    show: true // We will show it manually later
                })
                .on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
                    $('#userForm')
                        .show();                             // Show the login form
                })
                .on('hide.bs.modal', function(e) {
                    // Bootbox will remove the modal (including the body which contains the login form)
                    // after hiding the modal
                    // Therefor, we need to backup the form

                })
                .modal('show');



        });
    $('#payDate').datepicker({
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    }).on('change', function(){
        $('.datepicker').hide();
    });
```

Comment: Your code working only for the condition when we select date after clicking on datepicker but if we open datepicker window and just after that click on modal than it removes the form's content

Comment: One thing I want to mention In my actual code I am using two bootbox modal in same page If i remove this code '$('#userForm').hide().appendTo('body');' then I can't open both the pages after opening them first time. After opening them first time these are showing only blank popup. I don't know why this is happening but this code is responsible for opening them. If I remove this code then problem occurs